# Выходит ошибка с базой данных скулайт

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

У меня есть код скулайт и когда я запускаю бота выходит ошибка помогите
Сам код:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (name TEXT, id INT, cash BIGINT, rep INT, lvl INT, server_id INT, case_money INT)""")
    #создание магазина (одна строчка ниже)
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shop (role_id INT, id INT, cost BIGINT)""")

    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1, {guild.id}, 1)")
            else:
                pass

    connection.commit()
    print('bot connected')
```

Ошибка:

```
    cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1, {guild.id}, 1)")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "m": syntax error
```

Comment: Используйте параметрезированные запросы.

Comment: Не связано с вопросом (хотя, может и связано с ответом), но `f"INSERT INTO table VALUES ('{smth}');"` выглядит красиво, если `smht = "ok'); DROP TABLE users;"`. Классическая sql-инъекция.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, в нике пользователя `member` есть символ `'`, поэтому возникает ошибка синтаксиса.

Попробуйте **так**:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (name TEXT, id INT, cash BIGINT, rep INT, lvl INT, server_id INT, case_money INT)""")
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shop (role_id INT, id INT, cost BIGINT)""")

    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
                cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO users VALUES ("{str(member).replace("'", "")}", {member.id}, 0, 0, 1, {guild.id}, 1)""")
            else:
                pass

    connection.commit()
    print('bot connected')
```